# Wp_redirect and sending variables

Tags: wp-query, redirect

How to send some variables with wp_redirect() from function.php file in my theme folder?

```
if ( $post_id ) {
    $variable_to_send = '1';
    wp_redirect( home_url(), $variable_to_send );
    exit;
}
```

And on homepage I will catch the variable in if-else condition to show some confirmation or not depending if `$variable_to_send` = '1' or not.

How to do that in WordPress?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't do it this way.

`wp_redirect` is a fancy way to send header `Location` and the second argument of this function is request status, and not custom variable. (404, 301, 302, and so on).

You can send some variables as get parameters. So you can do something like this:

```
if ( $post_id ) {
        $variable_to_send = '1';
        wp_redirect( home_url() .'?my_variable='.$variable_to_send );
        exit;
}
```

Then you can use these variables as `$_GET['my_variable']` or register it as custom get variable.

Comment: You could also set a cookie, I suppose.

Comment: You need to use add_query_arg to do it the WordPress way.

Comment: @ShivanandSharma you may, but there is no need to use add_query_arg to add just one arg to URL without any other query args.

Answer (score 16):

Late to the party with this one, but the "Wordpress way" to do it would use [`add_query_arg`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) like so:

```
if ( $post_id ) {
    wp_redirect( esc_url( add_query_arg( 'variable_to_send', '1', home_url() ) ) );
    exit;
}
```

This will initiate a redirect to `http://my.website/?variable_to_send=1`. You'd be able to capture the variable, then, on the homepage (or blog page, depending on how your `home_url()` is setup) by accessing `$_GET['variable_to_send']` in your PHP code.

If you're going to do this in `functions.php`, make sure to hook onto `init` or a similarly early hook or else you will get a "Headers already sent" error.

Hopefully this helps someone who stumbles across this post.

Comment: If you're redirecting to a local address, you should use `wp_safe_redirect()`.